# $ \int^1_0 (\frac{1}{1-xt}) (\frac{1}{1-zt})(\sqrt{1-t})^3 dt $ using substitution $ y = (\frac{1}{1-xt}) (\frac{1}{1-zt}) $

Tags: integration

Consider the following integral

$$
\int^1_0 \left(\frac{1}{1-xt} \right) \left(\frac{1}{1-zt}\right)(\sqrt{1-t})^3 dt
$$

The following substitution

$$
y = \left(\frac{1}{1-xt} \right) \left(\frac{1}{1-zt}\right)
$$

doesn't eliminate both variables, given that there are two variables $x$ and $z$. How can I proceed?

Comment: Have you tried with $u=\sqrt{t-1}$ ?

Comment: Yes, but it led to an equally difficult expression.

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles than "tricky integral problem"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the substitution $u=\sqrt{1-t}$, we have $t=1-u^2\Rightarrow dt=-2u\,du$. Then:

$$\int^1_0 \left(\frac{1}{1-xt} \right) \left(\frac{1}{1-zt}\right)(\sqrt{1-t})^3 dt=2\int_0^1 \frac{u^4}{(1-x(1-u^2))(1-z(1-u^2))}\,du$$

$$=\frac{2}{xz}\int_0^1 \frac{u^4}{(u^2-a)(u^2-b)}\,du$$

where $a=1-\frac{1}{x}$ and $b=1-\frac{1}{z}$. Now, we have the following partial fraction representation:

$$\frac{u^4}{(u^2-a)(u^2-b)}=\frac{2a^2}{(a-b)(u^2-a)}-\frac{2b^2}{(a-b)(u^2-b)}+2$$

Can you end it from here?

Comment: Thank you, I did the first of your steps, but couldn't simplify it to your third step. Do you have a reference on a good place to learn the techniques you applied?

Comment: @RedPen, if you mean the partial fraction decomposition, it's pretty standard. You can read more here: https://brilliant.org/wiki/partial-fractions/